# read hyperopt parameters from json

Tags: json, python-3.x, hyperopt

I want to read [hyperopt](https://github.com/hyperopt/hyperopt) parameters from a JSON file.

My JSON file would be like:

```
[
    {
        "id": "121",
        "model": [
            {
                "model_name": "power",
                "estimator_type": [
                    {
                        "type": "Polynomial",
                        "degree": [2, 3, 4]
                    },
                    {
                        "type": "svm",
                        "C": [0, 1],
                        "kernel": [
                            {
                                "ktype": "linear"
                            },
                            {
                                "ktype": "RBF",
                                "width": [0, 1]
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ],
                "cut_values": {
                    "qids": ["1234"]
                }
            },
            {
                "model_name": "speed",
                "estimator_type": [
                    {
                        "type": "Polynomial",
                        "degree": ["quniform", 2, 3]
                    }
                ],
                "cut_values": null
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": "123",
        "model": [
            {
                "model_name": "power",
                "estimator_type": [
                    {
                        "type": "LinearRegression"
                    }
                ],
                "cut_values": null
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

I have checked  [this post](https://github.com/hyperopt/hyperopt/issues/507) but with no success for more complex JSON like the one above.

I want to be able to create a space like [2.2 A Search Space Example: scikit-learn](https://github.com/hyperopt/hyperopt/wiki/FMin#22-a-search-space-example-scikit-learn).

Comment: Something like [this](https://godbolt.org/z/GmNpif)?

Comment: @Azeem: Something like this, but I want to read all of this from a json file..

Comment: Right. And, this JSON file would always look like this or it could be more populated than this one? Did you try to write code for this? Please share that too.

Comment: @Azeem:It could be more populated at the "estimator type" field. I don't have some working code for that.